# Invisible elastic search fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search schema of the kind shown below

```
{
  "customer": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
    }
  }
}

{
  "activity": {
    "parent": {
      "type": "customer"
    },
    "routing": {
        "required": true,
        "path": "customer.id"
    },
    "properties": {
        ...
        // The parent object is included on activity
        "customer": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
            }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Where, customers have activities and activities are children of customer type. I also have the customer available directly on the activity type.

If I now write a terms filter against the activity type

```
{
    "terms": {
        "field": "customer.id"
    }
}
```

Which reads as - bucket all activities belonging to the same customer.

Surprisingly, this buckets `activity.id` instead of `activity.customer.id`. I'm stumped. Really truly.

I assumed this has something to do with the parent-child relation? I was able to get what I want by doing

```
{
    "terms": {
        "field": "_parent"
    }
}
```

I don't understand this. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been recently described in [this blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring#ambiguous-fields) and is one of the reasons why the ES 2.0 will undergo a big refactoring around  mappings. In short, the issue here is that in your mapping, `customer` is both a type name and a field name, so `customer.id` can refer to either the `id` field of the `customer` type or the `id` field of the `customer` object in the `activity` type.

So if you use the following fully-qualified field name instead, it should work as expected:

```
{
    "terms": {
        "field": "activity.customer.id"
    }
}
```